# How to implement scroll 2 fragments in a LinearLayout

Tags: android-fragments, scroll, android-recyclerview

First of all, this is my first question aske here, I'm kinda "newbie" on Android Development and also, my english skills aren't really good, so I will try to do my best. 
Please is something is unclear, I will appreciate if you could ask me what could I explain more.

So, the point is that i have an application with an Activity who loads differents fragments.

One of these fragments, loads 2 fragments on a LinearLayout, where the first one ([Caldroid Fragment](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)) should be: wrap_content (in order to display completely the calendar).

The second one, it's a fragment which contains a simple textview + a RecyclerView. My problem is that, this fragment has a really little space to show the items on the recyclerview ([image](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img538/3329/b5XCHh.png)).

How can I implement the hide of the CaldroidFragment just when I scroll through the Fragment with the RecyclerView?

I tried to put the Layout container of both fragments inside a ScrollView but it didnt work, and a lot of differents solutions related to this type of problems. I think this could be implemented with parallax or something, but im really sure that im falling in a XY problem.

That's why I ask some kind of help or pointer to understand my problem, what could I change in the implementation.

Thanks a lot for reading!

PS: I can't upload images because i have not the mininum 10 reputation points.

The XML code is:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:id="@+id/calendario"

            />

            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                         android:id="@+id/gastos"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
It was a problem from the library I was using. So nothing to do with it.